# What does configureDefaultServletHandling means?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand how does Spring MVC works, and I don't understand this part of code in my Spring configurations:

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

When this is in my `WebContextApplication` class, everything works fine and when it's not present everything works fine too. So what is the purpose of this method? Should my `WebContextApplication` class have this method? and why?

Comment: It tells Spring to use the container's default servlet for certain requests, like for static resources.  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html#what . It's a performance optimization

Comment: What don't you understand in the javadoc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.html. Do you have static resources. How are they handled?

Comment: Yes i have static resources, with this method `@Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/bootstrap/");
 }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As JB Nizet already tried to explain both are used to serve static resources.

So your question is that your Java based Spring configuration has

```
@Override 
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {     
    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/bootstrap/"); 
}
```

then why do you need

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

or why 
`<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` if you have

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/resources/bootstrap/" />
```

in terms of xml configuration.

---

To answer your question based on the requirements you have put you don't need to override `configureDefaultServletHandling()` as you have already overridden and provided your static resource mappings.

By overriding `addResourceHandlers()` method you are essentially asking `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` to serve the resources mentioned resource location.

However if you override `configureDefaultServletHandling()` and enabling it you are essentially asking default servlet (mapped to "/") to serve the resources. There are couple of things you need to take care here if you are using this. Quoting from [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) -

> This allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (thus overriding the mapping of the container’s default Servlet), while still allowing static resource requests to be handled by the container’s default Servlet. It configures a DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler with a URL mapping of "/**" and the lowest priority relative to other URL mappings.
>
> This handler will forward all requests to the default Servlet. Therefore it is important that it remains last in the order of all other URL HandlerMappings. That will be the case if you use  or alternatively if you are setting up your own customized HandlerMapping instance be sure to set its order property to a value lower than that of the DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler, which is Integer.MAX_VALUE.